# Need uiview to pdf component in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf-generation

I want to convert a UIView to pdf, is there any readymade component there, because i have less time to do that. if not can u give me example code for pdf

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Also make sure you import: QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h

Comment: Dude if i want to do pagination than

Answer (score 0):

click [Apple Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)` of Quartz Demo and you you can learn about PDF and different diagrams in uiviews.

Answer (score 0):

or try this https://github.com/vfr/Reader PDF Reader/Viewer

Answer (score 0):

**You can use PDFGenerator** [Link to GitHub](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator#features):

They also have a demo application on github.

Sample of code **fonte**: [Generating PDF from views](https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/PDFGenerator#generate-from-views-or-images):

```
func generatePDF() {
    let v1 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    let v2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 200.0))
    let v3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,y: 0, width: 100.0, height: 200.0))
    v1.backgroundColor = .red
    v1.contentSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 200.0)
    v2.backgroundColor = .green
    v3.backgroundColor = .blue

    let dst = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory().appending("sample1.pdf"))
    // outputs as Data
    do {
        let data = try PDFGenerator.generated(by: [v1, v2, v3])
        data.write(to: dst, options: .atomic)
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }

    // writes to Disk directly.
    do {
        try PDFGenerator.generate([v1, v2, v3], to: dst)    
    } catch (let error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```